# How to add a separator space between rows on custom Xamarin.Forms ViewCell?

Tags: c#, listview, grid, xamarin.forms, custom-cell

In [this question on Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20517/curved-corners-in-tableview-cells),
Craig Dunn teaches how to create a cell with frame.

I want to Add a space between each cell.

At present the cells seems glued, and the `ViewCell` doesn`t have a space property.

How can I add a separator space between rows on custom Xamarin.Forms ViewCell?

Comment: Please add the relevant code right into the question so people can know exactly what the problem is. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just have to customize the layout of the `MenuCell` further to achieve this.

Shown below is a version that uses a further `Xamarin.Forms.Frame` to create a spacing between each item with a couple other modifications:-

**XAML Page:-**

```
<ListView x:Name="lstItems" />
```

**XAML Code-Behind:-**

```
lstItems.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(Classes.MenuCell));
lstItems.ItemsSource = new string[] { "Apples", "Bananas", "Pears", "Oranges" };
```

**ViewCell class:-**

```
public class MenuCell : ViewCell
{
    public MenuCell()
    {
        Label objLabel = new Label
        {
            YAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
            TextColor = Color.Yellow,                
        };
        objLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("."));


        StackLayout objLayout = new StackLayout
        {
            Padding = new Thickness(20, 0, 0, 0),
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
            Children = { objLabel }
        };

        Frame objFrame_Inner = new Frame
        {
            Padding = new Thickness(15, 15, 15, 15),
            HeightRequest = 36,
            OutlineColor = Color.Accent,
            BackgroundColor = Color.Blue,
            Content = objLayout,                
        };

        Frame objFrame_Outer = new Frame
        {
            Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 10),
            Content = objFrame_Inner
        };

        View = objFrame_Outer;            
    }
}
```

Will result in the following:-

[image: ListView with spacing between each item.]

Comment: Essentially you need to pad a containing element. `<ViewCell><StackLayout Padding="10"><MyNestedRowLayout /></StackLayout></ViewCell>`

Answer (score 3):

my xaml example:

```
 <ListView BackgroundColor="Gray" SeparatorVisibility="None" ItemsSource="{Binding Shipments}" x:Name="lstShipments" RowHeight="60">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,1">
            <Grid VerticalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="White">
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"></ColumnDefinition>
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding DestinationCountry}" FontSize="16" />
              <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Source="box32.png" />
              <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ExchangeOfficeDestinationTitle}" FontSize="16" />
              <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ShipmentNum}" FontSize="10" />

            </Grid>
          </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

[image]

Comment: is that the full xaml code for your card listview? i'm trying your xaml code and am getting nothing close to your screenshot I have a post over here if you have a minute to look at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37144141/how-to-make-a-card-style-listview-in-xamarin-forms